# Following Helix Principles, which Project to place tile and icon fields in a multi site configuration?

Tags: helix

I'm very new to Helix Principles.

I'm having a multisite configured Helix Project Setup having all the layers defined. I have currently placed all the Site Icon fields, Title, Analytics fields inside the Foundation project.

I'm confused about whether those should be placed inside the foundation layer.
I have defined a controller to render the fields from a Site Configuration folder template created inside the CMS.
Below is my Sitecore CMS structure

[image]

And, below is my Project Structure

[image]

Thanks to anyone, who has read my first question in this forum. I'm also thankful to any person for your help and comment.

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange :) 

if those project-depending icons should be under the Project layer. 
If it's multi-site shared icons - that it can be under Foundation Layer. 

Also, you can separate Implementation and interfaces into two different Foundation projects. 

It will be flexible in the future when your project will be referenced to an abstraction project and you will need a make another implementation for your icons.

Comment: Hi Vadin, thanks a lot for your response. I will be adding interfaces as a separate foundation project.


Should the Interfaces defined inside the Feature project will also follow a separate project for each feature or a single common project that has all the interfaces for all features?

Thanks.

Comment: I can do it as an answer if I answered on your question

Comment: If not ask me I can answer your question and then summarize it as final answer.

Comment: Thanks Vadim, Sure Please go ahead, I will post it as the answer to my question.

Comment: Regarding your question. As for the feature, it depends. If your feature allows separating on abstract layer and implementation - go ahead. But in the feature case, you can't reference the feature project to another feature project. In

Comment: @SumanBaul Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange, based on my experience and what i see on your screenshot i am sure that it should be feature lvl

Comment: @pblrok Thanks for the reply. Are there any guidelines or examples to follow? I couldn't find any details about this in helix documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to **Sitecore Stack Exchange** :)

As I mentioned in the comments it depends on your purposes of using these icons. If those **project-depending** icons should be under the **Project** layer.

If it's **multi-site shared** icons that can be used in different places (on website level, on components level, etc. - that it can be under **Foundation** Layer. Also, you can separate Implementation and interfaces into two different Foundation projects. It will be flexible in the future when your project will be referenced to an abstraction project and you will need a make another implementation for your icons.

If your icons it's **just a feature** for your website - just move them to a **Feature** level. As [pblrok](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/4791/pblrok) mentioned in comments.

Be careful, the architecture question sometimes breaking our brain if thinking a lot about it.
If you faced with some challenges about it - **Sitecore Stack Exchange** will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, Vadin Birkos for your kind words.

Yes creating a project from scratch and following architectures is surely breaking our brains. Thanks for your immense help. :)